# Small footprint php framework suggestions

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm working on a small project, where I'm using the codeigniter php framework, but find it's got a bit too much bloat for my purpose.

Essentially I'd like something to make database interaction, sessions and validations simpler. MVC would be nice too.

What I'm looking for is something that has 10 php files tops. 
When I'm adding some php functionality to a mostly html site, something like CodeIgniter just doesn't fit the bill.

Any suggestions ?

---

**edit:**

I'm not looking for a templating engine. And Kohona is a bit bigger than necessary (for me - for my purpose).

I came across [elf-php](http://www.elf-php.com/), has anyone worked with that yet? IT looks like it has the essentials I'm looking for and some decent documentation. But this is just an impression.

It's hard for me to tell what the Fari-MVC does without playing around with it. I could go through the code and see the annotation, but I haven't found much else for docs.

Comment: You could always make your own framework, something you can tailor to your own needs.

Comment: Fari: Yeah, the code is thoroughly documented and if you need any pointers I will be very glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fat-Free Framework](http://fatfree.sf.net/) is self-contained in a single 55KB file. If you want more features, there are plugins to extend it.

Comment: I did come across this framework sometime in the past year. It really seems like it would do the job, But I'm not doing any php lately, and I probably will not get a chance to test it anytime soon.

Comment: Just came across this again by chance, I have been doing a bit of PHP since, and Fat-Free is my go to framework for small and mid-size stuff. This nice micro-framework stays out of your way, has great routing, and several helpers to allow things such as interfacing with databases out of the box. Only con is could use a bit more documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You could always try [MicroMVC](http://micromvc.com/). Looks like a small project created by SO user [Xeoncross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99923/xeoncross). No idea how good/complete it is...but it could be fun.

Comment: According to Ruilog, it's the [Fastest PHP framework there is](http://www.ruilog.com/blog/view/b6f0e42cf705.html). Contains all the common things you need like ORM, Request/Response, & Encryption libraries in very few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

For this sort of sized site (and for somewhat larger ones too) I'd just use a template system and not worry about an MVC framework - even the lightest are lot of overhead for a few pages.  I'd highly recommend [TinyButStrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com).  It's simply superb - perfect separation of code and design, powerful but not overly complex, and integrates perfectly with Dreamweaver so you, or your designer, can design templates wysiwyg.

I've had a fair bit of success combining this with [XAJAX](http://www.xajaxproject.org/), which isn't one of your more popular AJAX frameworks, but has some nice features.  The beauty of just using a template system like TBS though is you can pull in whatever, and just whatever, libraries you need.  Personally I dislike abstracting out SQL, but there's a fair number of stand-alone libraries to choose from if you so desire.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, as a general answer, you can find a great amount of small php frameworks on **Ohloh**:

http://www.ohloh.net/tags/framework/php

You can then select the one you like based on previewing the source, the documentation quality, the number of users that use it etc.

Answer (score 1):

*This was 2009/2010, there are probably better things out there now.*

**Fari MVC Framework**

Source: https://github.com/radekstepan/Fari-Framework

For example I wrote a chat app in it: https://github.com/radekstepan/Clubhouse

**Soprano**

Source: https://github.com/radekstepan/soprano

A good minimal example if you want to write your own.

Comment: Oh and it contains a demo app that works from a flat file database so you can test it pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

There are some newer offerings to pick from now:

TinyMVC:   http://www.tinymvc.com/

TinyPHP:   http://tinyphp.us/

KissMVC:   http://kissmvc.com/

I'm about to try doing a small project with TinyMVC.

Comment: and looks like they all have at least basic Model ORM

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer the question... but if CI has a bit too much bloat for you, maybe you can try [Kohana](http://www.kohanaphp.com/), which is a bit less bloated than CI (started as a fork).

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at CakePHP?

http://cakephp.org/

Comment: CakePHP contains even more bloat than CodeIgniter.

Comment: Cake is heavier than CI!